# Word order with hear obj participle in passive voice

Tags: word-order, passive-voice

> I could hear the men at the campfire singing.

If I change this sentence into passive ,

- The men at the campfire could be heard singing.
- The men could be heard singing at the campfire.
- The men could be heard at the campfire singing.

Which is more natural ?

Comment: I think both are possible but pretty unsure

Comment: This is a matter of style, and not a grammatical question. None is more natural than any other!

Comment: To be grammatically , what should I use ?

Comment: They are all grammatically correct. Your question concerns style, and _not_ grammar._

Comment: All of these work and all of these are natural.  Whichever you mention first will be considered more important slightly than the rest.

Comment: The meaning of each is slightly different.  "The men at the campfire..." implies that the men were at the campfire, but the person hearing them could be somewhere else.  "...could be heard singing at the campfire" is ambiguous; it could mean that the men were at the campfire, or only that they could be heard by someone at the campfire.  "...could be heard at the campfire singing" is probably the most poetic and least likely version, and could mean either the men or the hearer were at the campfire.